# What is the proper handling for NuGet packages in a .NET solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a C# solution consisting of different projects.

```
MySolution
+-- Project1
+-- Project2
|   +-- packages.config
+-- Project3
+-- packages
|   +-- System.Linq.4.0.0
|   +-- System.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.1.3.2
```

I have NuGet dependencies as you can see.

#### Declaring dependencies, installing them

My point is that Visual Studio has created `packages.config` with the list of the dependencies I need inside the project that actually needs those dependencies. And I guess this is fine.

Also, Visual Studio installs all the packages in a folder which is in the solution folder. This is fine too because projects like `Project1` (which depends on `Project2`) need to refer those packages as well.

#### Questions

My doubts are on this arrangement:

1. Isn't it better to have packages defined in `packages.config` in the solution folder rather than in one of the projects?
2. If projects use different NuGet packages, the `packages.config` in the solution folder will enumerate all of them. Is it fine?
3. If I remove the `packages.config` from each project and add a `packages.config` in the solution folder, will Visual Studio update that file everytime I update/add/remove packages?
4. Would this be a recommended approach?

Note that I have tried this and it seems to be fine except for point 3 where Visual Studio does not seems to recognize the packages I have installed. Apart from that point, this question is very best-practice related.

Comment: Have you thought about multiple solution files in the same folder?

Comment: @MichaelSpranger Well I don't see any goodness in that? What for? By solution file you mean `package.config`? The solution file would be `MySolution.sln`, I guess you have a typo...

Comment: I mean multiple .sln files in one folder. We do this sometimes when we want to combine projects in different combinations into a solution.

Comment: @MichaelSpranger But how is this supposed to help me?

Comment: It is not supposed to "help" you. I merely wanted to raise the question if your proposed setup would support multiple .sln files in one folder.

Comment: @MichaelSpranger I see. In my case not really. Normally you use multiple sln files for having different group arrangements for your projects. In my case that is not what I need. Just wanted kind of a central place to declare my dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

OK this is what I do and you can do too.

In your solution, create a project say MyProject.Nugets. Install all Nugets into this project. Output of this project will be a folder inside development folder. All your other project will refer dlls from this folder and no other project will have `packages.config`.

**Benefits:**

1. All projects will be referring same version of a package.
2. Centralized controlling project for Nugets instead of multiple packages.config.

Comment: My detailed blog on this 
https://nikhilagrawal.net/2017/04/25/how-to-handle-nugets-in-todays-multi-project-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

You want the packages.config per each project in the solution so you can track what packages are needed for the solution. U can manage the packages per project or per solution. This allows you to have different versions of the same package in different projects. 
If you are not familiar with package manager  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui. Other than that just set up your package restore.

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet team [deprecated solution level packages](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522) in NuGet 3.0 and they would not plan to support them going forward. There is a [discussion](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1521) about bringing back solution level packages in a way that is compatible with Visual Studio 2013 for a future version of NuGet.

This deprecation was not published visibly and detailed reasons. From my personal experience, the reason for this deprecation should be the problem of different projects referring to different versions of the same package which isn't possible with solution-level packages.